# How to make sure that I did not write in the controller: @feedback.errors.add And received the correct error message from the locale in view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My Question: Output errors messages validate for form.

I can output this which help controller and model:
@feedback.errors.add :email, `t('mongoid.errors.models.modern.feedback.attributes.email.invalid')`
But when i write it:

```
@feedback.errors.add :email, :invalid
```

I get output 'is invalid' instead locale message: 'Email invalid format'

How to make than i don`t have code in controller about it
And my view output locales error instead 'is invalid'?

How to make sure that I did not write in the controller: @feedback.errors.add
And received the correct error message from the locale in view?

Answer (score 0):

Do not write the validation in the controller. Only except on specific cases, you'd usually should write these validations in the models.

*app/models/feedback.rb*

```
class Feedback < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :email, format: { with: /\A([a-z0-9\+_\-]+)(\.[a-z0-9\+_\-]+)*@([a-z0-9\-]+\.)+[a-z]{2,6}\z/ix }
end
```

By default the error message for the validation above is mapped to the locale message:

`mongoid.errors.models.feedback.attributes.email.invalid`

or if using activerecord:

`activerecord.errors.models.feedback.attributes.email.invalid`

See mapping documentation [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#translations-for-active-record-models) for details.

Take note that in the documentation, :format is mapped to :invalid key.

Now, you can customise the error message by updating the locale file:

*config/locales/en.yml (example)*

```
en:
  mongoid:
    errors:
      models:
        feedback:
          attributes:
            email:
              invalid: "Email address provided is invalid."
```

After implementing this, you shouldn't need to have to write `@feedback.errors.add` in the controller